# Java while loop text formatting

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

**Inputs**

```
Hi.
Bye.
#
```

**Actual outputs:**

```
h(1)i(1)
```

**Expected outputs:**

```
h(1) i(1)
b(1) e(1) y(1)
```

There must be a gap between both items. How do I need to modify my `while` loop so `#` will indicate stop?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a[] = new int[26];

        Scanner sc =  new Scanner (System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();     
                        
        for (char ch : str.toCharArray())
            if (ch >= 65 && ch <= 90)
                a[ch - 65]++;
            else if (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122)
                a[ch - 97]++;   
            
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            if (a[i] > 0)
                System.out.print((char)(i + 97) + "(" + a[i] + ")");    
    }       
}
```

Comment: To end the process, test for a hash before you enter the loop.  Add a space to the end parenthesis in the print in the last for loop.

Comment: Read [Why is it considered inappropriate and unprofessional to type in all capital letters](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-considered-inappropriate-and-unprofessional-to-type-in-all-capital-letters)

Answer (score 1):

**First question**

Seems you just need to add a space at the end of the print. You have this:

```
System.out.print( (char)(i+97)+ "(" + a[i]+")");
```

It should be:

```
System.out.print( (char)(i+97)+ "(" + a[i]+") "); // Added a space at the end.
```

Or you could also print the space later:

```
System.out.print( (char)(i+97)+ "(" + a[i]+")");
System.out.print(" ");
```

**Second question**

About the while-loop, you could wrap what you have within the loop and should work, something like:

```
// This will be used for the initial value ONLY, in your example, it should be the "Hi"
String str = sc.nextLine();

while (!str.equals("#")) {
    int a[]=new int[26];

    for(int i = 0; i<str.length();i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i)>=65 && str.charAt(i)<=90) {
            a[str.charAt(i)-65]++;
        }
        else if(str.charAt(i)>=97 && str.charAt(i)<=122) {
            a[str.charAt(i)-97]++;
        }
    }           
        
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++) {
        if(a[i]>0) {                    
            System.out.print( (char)(i+97)+ "(" + a[i]+")");
        }                   
    }

    System.out.println(); // Printing new line to split next output

    // This will be for the next inputs you have, in your example: "Bye" and "#"
    str = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Good catch, just added it in the code block

Answer (score 0):

The space can be added into the print statement.
The loop can end when user enters # character.
Added one extra println to improve appearance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "";
        int a[];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!(str = sc.nextLine()).equals("#")) {
            a = new int[26];
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                if (str.charAt(i) >= 65 && str.charAt(i) <= 90) {
                    a[str.charAt(i) - 65]++;
                } else if (str.charAt(i) >= 97 && str.charAt(i) <= 122) {
                    a[str.charAt(i) - 97]++;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                if (a[i] > 0) {

                    System.out.print((char) (i + 97) + "(" + a[i] + ") "); // space added
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");  //  looks better with this
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```